# Image Uploader Using Random Image

Tags: bug, images

I am tryin to add an image and the image I selected is *not* what is displayed in [Typeset Only First n Items or Items after n from a List](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/579563/4301).

I have acreen shots of what I am trying to upload but of course since I can't properly include an image that does not help in this situation.

Comment: This is a network-wide issue, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359772/295232

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been fixed (on Imgur's side). For more details on what happened, see [I am getting the wrong image when uploading a picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359778/168244).